# Compile error when trying to get an iterator from a container

Tags: c++

I get the following error:

```
error: conversion from 'std::vector<shape*>::const_iterator 
to non-scalar type 'std::vector<shape*>::iterator
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on?

```
template <typename Container>
void draw_all(const Container &c)
{
    for (typename Container::iterator p= c.begin(); p != c.end(); p++)
    {
        (*p)->draw();
    }
}
```

main

```
vector<shape *> vs;
draw_all(vs);
```

Comment: Please use a more descriptive subject line next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly what the error message says: you're attempting to get a non-const iterator from a const object. Instead do:

```
typename Container::const_iterator p = c.begin();
```

Comment: You could also use the new `std::begin(c);` (with C++11)

Comment: @Drahakar C++0x is now officially called C++11, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `const Container`, and calling `begin()` on it will give you a `const_iterator`, not an `iterator` (since you're not allowed to modify the contents). So use a `const_iterator` instead, or take a non-const reference as your input.

Obviously, `draw()` is assumed to be a const member function as well if you're using a `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

You container is a constant reference, so you can only use `const_iterator`s on it and only call `const` methods. Try instead

```
template <typename Container>
void draw_all(Container &c)
{
    for (typename Container::iterator p= c.begin(); p != c.end(); p++)
    {
        (*p)->draw();
    }
}
```

or make the iterator and your `draw()` method `const`.